# How do I programmatically set a taxonomy term for a node?

Tags: nodes, 8, taxonomy-terms

I got some difficulties setting a taxonomy for a node. Currently I am using this code.

```
$node = Node::create(array(
    'type' => 'detailseite',
    'title' => $data[$headlineIndex],
    'langcode' => 'de',
    'uid' => '1',
    'status' => 1,
    'field_headline' => $data[$headlineIndex],
    'field_intro' => $data[$introIndex] . $categories[$data[$categoryIndex]],
    'created' => $data[$dateIndex],
    'field_autor' => $data[$autorIndex],
    'field_teaser_text' => $data[$shortIndex],
    'field_fields' => array(),
));
$node->save();
```

Which works fine so far (below an image of the fields of "detailseite").

[image]

Everything gets set correctly and I can find the newly created nodes in the admin area that work correctly.
Now I need to set 'field_meldungstyp' which is an Entity-Reference to a Taxonomy:

[image]

which already contains three entries:

I want to get the node(s) I created programmatically to have "field_meldungstyp" set to "Artikel" of the "Meldungstyp"-Vocabulary.

I already tried adding:

```
'field_meldungstyp' => array( 'tid' => 19 ),
```

where 19 is the tid of "Artikel" of the earlier mentioned vocabulary. And that's where I'm stuck.
Also https ://www.drupal.org/node/2402811 didn't work for me. As well as

```
$node->field_meldungstyp[$node->language][]['tid'] = 19;
```

didn't work either.

simply adding

```
$node = Node::create(array(
    ...
    'field_meldungstyp' => 19,
    ...
));
```

results in crashing with the following error:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'datetime' for column 'created' at row 1: INSERT INTO {taxonomy_index} (nid, tid, status, sticky, created) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 343 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 19 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => datetime ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 770 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Statement->execute(Array, Array) (Line: 610)
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query('INSERT INTO {taxonomy_index} (nid, tid, status, sticky, created) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4)', Array, Array) (Line: 81)
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection->query('INSERT INTO {taxonomy_index} (nid, tid, status, sticky, created) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4)', Array, Array) (Line: 32)
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Insert->execute() (Line: 371)
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Merge->execute() (Line: 525)
>   taxonomy_build_node_index(Object) (Line: 479)
>   taxonomy_node_insert(Object)
>   call_user_func_array('taxonomy_node_insert', Array) (Line: 402)
>   Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('node_insert', Array) (Line: 167)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->invokeHook('insert', Object) (Line: 418)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook('insert', Object) (Line: 470)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPostSave(Object, ) (Line: 304)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPostSave(Object, ) (Line: 395)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object) (Line: 761)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object) (Line: 364)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() (Line: 46)
>   Drupal\awo_importer\Controller\T3ImporterController->import()
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 574)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
>   call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 144)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 64)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 98)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 77)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
>   Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 628)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It needs to be a nested array.

```
'field_meldungstyp'  => [
      ['target_id' => 12345]
    ]
```

Try this:

```
$node = Node::create(array(
    'type' => 'detailseite',
    'title' => $data[$headlineIndex],
    'langcode' => 'de',
    'uid' => '1',
    'status' => 1,
    'field_headline' => $data[$headlineIndex],
    'field_intro' => $data[$introIndex] . $categories[$data[$categoryIndex]],
    'created' => $data[$dateIndex],
    'field_autor' => $data[$autorIndex],
    'field_teaser_text' => $data[$shortIndex],
    'field_meldungstyp'  => [
      ['target_id' => 12345]
    ]
));
$node->save();
```

Comment: That somewhat crashes too with (I exchanged `12345` to `19` accordingly ;) )`Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'datetime' for column 'created' at row 1: INSERT INTO {taxonomy_index} (nid, tid, status, sticky, created) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 188 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 19 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => ... in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save()`

Comment: you have an error with your "created" field, it needs to be a unix timestamp.  If you remove created from your array, the error will go away.  Try it.

Answer (score 16):

In Drupal 7, taxonomy reference fields existed which used the pattern `['tid' => NUMBER]`. These are entity reference fields. The [EntityReferenceItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!Plugin!Field!FieldType!EntityReferenceItem.php/class/EntityReferenceItem/8.2.x) has the property definitions: `target_id` and `entity`. The former is a either an integer or string depending on the entity reference item's settings (basically config/content entity type).

This is also a similar question to [How to set value for multivalue field in drupal 8 programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199044/how-to-set-value-for-multivalue-field-in-drupal-8-programmatically)

So try to use the pattern

As part of Entity::create

```
Node::create([
  'field_meldungstyp' => [['target_id' => 19]]
]);
```

Using FieldableEntityInterface::set

```
$entity->set('field_meldungstyp', ['target_id' => 19]);
```

Using TypedDataInterface::setValue on the field item directly.

```
$entity->field_meldungstyp->setValue(['target_id' => 19]);
```

With magic method

```
$entity->field_meldungstyp->target_id = 19;
```

Note that this overwrites any current values of the field.

Comment: I find [Content Entity](https://www.drupal.org/node/2143503) documentation a bit incomplete as it is not clear how to set a field item other than the value magic method. For base fields it's a string or integer, but field items it should include the full field item list values?

Comment: Unfortunately still results in -syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'- for me when I add any of those right before $node->save. Even if I change the whole thing over to something like "entity_create('node', $node)" and removing Node::create, the line results in a crash. Maybe there is something wrong with my Drupal install itself of I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you see the syntax error in my answer? Correct it. It should be `=>` not `=`. :-)

Comment: I guess I really need a break ;D (working on that the whole day already), `=>` still gives me `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`.

Comment: Got it to "work" now i.e. it doesn't crash on me any more but the field unfortunately still doesn't get set on the generated nodes.

Comment: "$entity->field_meldungstyp->value = [['target_id' => 19]];". That's not correct. What you want is $entity->field_meldungstyp->target_id = 19. Note that also just providing 19 without the array works for set(), setValue() and even $node->field-meldungstyp = 19 should work for a single value field. The field type will attempt to convert it into the correct stucture automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how i did it for D8.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

//To create new node
$node = Node::create(['type' => 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_HERE']);

//To load a node by its ID
//$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(NODE_ID);

$nodeTerms = [1,2,3...]; // 1,2,3 = terms IDs
$node->set('YOUR_FIELD_OF_TERMS', $nodeTerms);
$node->save();
```

//To create new tax

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

$new_term = Term::create([
    'vid' => "YOUR_VOCABULARY_MACHINE_NAME",
    'name' => "NAME_OF_YOUR_TERM",
]);
$new_term->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to update the node after creation, like this:

```
$node = Node::create(array(
    ...
));
$node->save();
$node->field_meldungstyp->target_id = 19;
$node->save();
```

Comment: Tried that too initally and it crashed. I'll add the output to the top.

Comment: okey - so try target_id

Comment: Unfortunately same results/error-message. :(

Comment: Then I would update the field after creation (save) - updated my answer. Have you tried the nested array with the key target_id ?

Comment: Yeah, tried it, unfortunately same error as here [link[(http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217396/how-do-i-programmatically-set-a-taxonomy-term-for-a-node/217400?noredirect=1#comment265592_217419)

Comment: okey - but thats while creation ? not while updating ?? In Node::create you should skip field_meldungstyp

Comment: Tried both ways to no avail unfortunately i.e. `'field_meldungstyp' => array(array('target_id' => 19)),` inside `Node::create` as well as without anything of `'field_meldungstyp` inside it but with `$node->save();
$node->field_meldungstyp->target_id = 19;
$node->save();` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got this working in D9:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
  'type' => 'content type',
  'title' => 'node title',
  'field_tax_ref' => ['target_id' => '3'],
]);
$node->save();
```

field_tax_ref is a taxonomy entity reference field.

'3' is the tid of the term I want to reference.